# Give sum with reference

Tags: excel

What formula for all target  columns value needs to sum and need to get in total target columns with sum value but when I change a value in target columns that total target columns of sum is not showing correct value. For ref. Look at the image.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ruOTz.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this formula in cell L5

```
=SUMIF($C$3:$J$3,"*"&"TARGET"&"*",$C5:$J5)
```

[image: SUMIF]